# Array values gets overrided with the latest values angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am working on arrays where i am using map function to alter the data. i have an array of icons as shown below.

```
private socialIcons:any[] = [
      {"icon":"thumbs-up","operation":"like"},
      {"icon":"thumbs-down","operation":"unlike"},
      {"icon":"eye","operation":"view"},
      {"icon":"text","operation":"comment"},
    ];
```

Above is the array of icons which I will be passing into the child component. I am retrieving the data from backend using service calls. I am using the map to alter the data as shown below.

```
this.esServices.loadEsdata(obj).pipe(map(res=>res.json())).subscribe(res=>{

        res.map(x=>{
         x["socialIcons"] = this.socialIcons
            x["socialIcons"].map(icon=>{
              switch(icon.operation){
                  case 'like':{
                      icon["value"] = x["nooflikes"]
                       break;
                  }
                  case 'unlike':{
                      icon["value"] = x["nooflikes"]
                      break;
                  }
                  case 'view':{
                      icon["value"] = x["views"]
                      break;
                  }
                  case 'comment':{
                      icon["value"] = x["noofcomments"]
                      break;
                  }
              }

           })
          console.log(x)
          return x;
        }),
        this.datacount = res.length;
        this.creatives = this.creatives.concat(res);

      })
```

The problem is that ...x["socialIcons"] of second element overrides the x["socialIcons"] of first element in res. To be more clear.
console output of the first element
expected output:

```
[0:{
    resource_name: "potterypainting_40.jpg"
    socialIcons: Array(4)
    0: {icon: "thumbs-up", operation: "like", value: 1}
    1: {icon: "thumbs-down", operation: "unlike", value: 1}
    2: {icon: "eye", operation: "view", value: 0}
    3: {icon: "text", operation: "comment", value: 0}
    length: 4
    }]
```

Note: Checked with breakpoint as well, I am getting the output as expected in the first iteration, but as the second iteration starts values of array obtained in first iteration gets overridden with the values of the second iteration as shown below. hence the socailIcon arrays in both elements will be the same which is wrong.
Obtained output

```
[0:{
        resource_name: "potterypainting_40.jpg"
        socialIcons: Array(4)
        0: {icon: "thumbs-up", operation: "like", value: 0}
        1: {icon: "thumbs-down", operation: "unlike", value: 0}
        2: {icon: "eye", operation: "view", value: undefined}
        3: {icon: "text", operation: "comment", value: 0}
        length: 4
        }]
```

console output of the second element

```
[1:{
    resource_name: "streetart_41.jpg"
    socialIcons: Array(4)
    0: {icon: "thumbs-up", operation: "like", value: 0}
    1: {icon: "thumbs-down", operation: "unlike", value: 0}
    2: {icon: "eye", operation: "view", value: undefined}
    3: {icon: "text", operation: "comment", value: 0}
    length: 4
   }]
```

Observe that resource_name for both are different but only the socialIcons gets overridden by the latest one.

Please let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: the problem might be caused by this line:  `x["socialIcons"] = this.socialIcons` , why `this.socialIcons` is the same all time?!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I need it for all the elements but value for each iteration changes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `map` operator works.
You have to assign it to something.

Try this:

```
x['socialIcons'] = this.socialIcons;
x['socialIcons'] = x['socialIcons'].map(icon => { // This line
  switch (icon.operation) {
    case 'like': {
      icon['value'] = x['nooflikes'];
      break;
    }
    case 'unlike': {
      icon['value'] = x['nooflikes'];
      break;
    }
    case 'view': {
                                icon['value'] = x['views'];
                                break;
    }
    case 'comment': {
      icon['value'] = x['noofcomments'];
      break;
    }
  }
});
```